# How do i speed up this maxmind db query?

Tags: php, mysql

We are currently using this query to search a maxmind db that we host locally:

```
$db_result = mysql_query("select countryCode from example_table where $num BETWEEN beginIpNum AND endIpNum LIMIT 1");
```

When we remove the query from our page, it loads almost a second faster (roughly 0.7s to 0.8s)
and we could really use that time.

Thoughts on how to improve this?

Would adapting code to mysqli improve speed at all?

Comment: Do you have indexes on the table for `beginUpNum` and `endIpNum`?

Comment: Step 1: Make sure you have the right bottleneck and are working on tweaking the right thing. Throw out PHP from the equation and run the query directly against the database. You won't get any speed improvements by switching client library if the query itself is slow.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing is a best technique for improving speed of query execution. Columns used in where should be indexed which will return results faster.
So Apply indexes on beginIpNum and endIpNum fields respectively.
For more information about sql index
please refer the below link
http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-index.htm

Answer (score 0):

The quick "fix" is to make sure you have an appropriate covering index:

```
on example_table (beginIpNum, endIpNum, countryCode)
```

---

Test the query against the database using mysql command line client (or SQLYog, et al.), for timing, and to verify your SQL statement is making use of the index (EXPLAIN).